# I am not sure how to create a getter and setter for data member like: QMap<QString, QVariant> content[2]

Tags: c++, qt

first of all I'd rather create the array dynamically.  Need instructions, since I don't want to guess how many key/value pairs I'm getting from JSON Document.
secondly,  I need to know how to write the getter and setter for a class like this.
I'll appreciate a detail explanation please.

```
// this is a sample class 

class A : QOBject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QMap<QString, QVariant> content[2]
};
```

Comment: Why mess with C-style arrays? I'd use a QVector<QVariantMap> instead, which also solves the "dynamically" requirement.

Comment: I need to know how to write the getter and setter for a class like this. and/or for QVector<QVariantMap>
I'll appreciate a detail explanation please.